# Does the income from a product or art count as passive income?

Tags: labor-economics, money

When a writer publishes his book, can we classify the income from the book as passive? Or another example, when a musician publishes his album, does the album generates passive income, making any form of art or production process as passive income?

Comment: How is “passive income” defined? I think it exists as a tax concept in the US. The accounting treatment depends upon the jurisdiction.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Passive income is income that requires little to no effort to earn and maintain."  Maybe the notion is not correct fully. I want to learn what does creating a product (whether it is a piece of art, machine, or software, etc.) can be called in terms of economics.